# Flutter firebase Unhandled Exception: PlatformException

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, error-handling, unhandled-exception

```
I want to connect my flutter app to firebase but I get this error how can I fix it
Error;
E/flutter ( 7531): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter ( 7531): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource
messages.pigeon.dart:246
E/flutter ( 7531): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7531): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
method_channel_firebase.dart:89
E/flutter ( 7531): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7531): #2      Firebase.initializeApp
firebase.dart:43
E/flutter ( 7531): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7531): #3      main
main.dart:13
E/flutter ( 7531): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7531):

This code;
 FloatingActionButton.small(
                    onPressed: () {
                      void IncermentCounter() {
                        setState(() {
```

//here I made the counter button to check that the firebase is connected
DatabaseReference testFirebase = FirebaseDatabase
.instance
.reference()
.child("testFirebase");

```
                          counter++;
                          testFirebase.set(counter);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
                  )
Plugins;
firebase_core: ^2.7.0
  firebase_database: ^10.0.14
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have not correctly configured Firebase in your code.

Ensure you have added all the required dependencies and initialized the Firebase in your main class.

Similar to this:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```

Check out the below documentation for firebase setup:

[Firebase official documentation link for set up!](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)